# Cocoa Touch - Changing the text of a button and a label

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, uilabel

Well.. I forgot how to change the text of a button and label in cocoa touch.

Please remind me..

```
IBOutlet id questionLabel;
IBOutlet id answerButtonOne;
IBOutlet id answerButtonTwo;
IBOutlet id answerButtonThree;
IBOutlet id answerButtonFour;
```

Comment: Opps my internet double posted it. I deleted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UILabel* label;
label.text = @"Foo";
```

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/text

```
UIButton* button;
[button setTitle:@"Bar" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setTitle:forState: